# exporting firebase function results in "function.js does not exist" error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I currently export my functions as follows:

```
// My function file: class-http.f.ts
export default functions.https.onRequest(server)


// main.ts
exports.api_class = require('./app/microservices/class/http/class-http.f')
```

That works fine, with the exception that my function name results in `api_class-default`. I prefer it just be `api_class`, so I tried this method of exporting instead:

```
// My function file: class-http.f.ts
exports.api_class = functions.https.onRequest(server)


// main.ts
export * from './app/microservices/class/http/class-http.f'
```

This works with the emulator, but fails during deploy, with the resulting error: `function.js does not exist`.

It would be nice to know why this is happening and if I can achieve the desired function name as noted above.

**Edit 1**

My built code directory looks like this:

```
assets (folder)
main.js
main.js.map
package.json
```

**Edit 2**

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.17",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.17",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.17",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19"
  },
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

Comment: hey there, could you please share the path where your `function.js` and the `package.json` are located?

Comment: @SamuelRomero I don't actually have a `function.js`, oddly enough. The built code resides in `main.js`. Added the directory of my `dist` folder to the question.

Comment: Could you please share the content of your package.json?

Comment: @SamuelRomero ^^

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. Your files look right. So, it seems like this is not related to them. However, I would like to know if you are using a VPC in your environment. On the other hand, the verbosity flag at the end of the command you are using (--verbosity=debug) will be very useful to get more detail about this issue

Comment: @SamuelRomero not using a VPC. I've elevated this to the Firebase team and they're investigating at the moment.